# widget_test.dart seems to not detect the app.?

Tags: flutter, dart

*so this the widget_test.dart*

[image: Screenshot error]

*and these are the problems*

[image: Screenshot error 2]

Answer (score 0):

check `pubspec.yaml` file whether you have included `flutter` and `flutter_test` appropriately

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

and make sure indentation in yaml file is correct.

if problem does not solved. run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Comment: it's still not working